# Error message on registering registered user in fosuserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

Is there any way to show a flashbag message into `FOSUuserBundle`'s `register.html.twig` once the user has already registered but is trying to register again?

Example:

> This username/email is already registered, please check your mail or register with another account

What code do I need to include in `RegistrationController.php`?

Comment: Here the doc, you can hooking into controller events or overriding controller https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOSUserBundle already uses the [`UniqueEntity`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) assert to check wether a username has already been taken by default.

You can find it in i.e. [Resources\config\validation\orm.yml](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/validation/orm.xml#L8) for doctrine ORM.

An non-free username will trigger a form validation error for the field 'username' with the message `fos_user.username.already_used`.